# Migrate Jenkins plugins from PROD to DEV

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I want to clone our Jenkins PROD environment to create a DEV environment. The SA cloned the servers for me but reinstalled Jenkins because they don't want to have all PROD settings there. So now I need to reconfigure this new Jenkins.

There are dozens of plugins installed in PROD, can I just copy the /plugin folder and overwrite the new Jenkins? It's too much work to find the exact version of each plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I did a copy and restart the service, it works.